# Parameter behind url from select option

Tags: php, html, parameters

I can't seem to find any answer on stack or any other site, I've searched for quite some time. What I'm trying to do is to put the selected option behind the `index.php?` so it will look like `index.php?%ordernumber%`. How can I accomplish this?
 Sorry if my question isn't formatted right, English isn't my native language, sorry.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/logic/orders/werkplaats/index.php?id=" method="post">
<div class="styled-select">
    <label for="inputProductieorder">Productieorder</label>
    <select name="productieorder" id="inputProductieorder" class="form-control">
        <?php
        global $db;

        $smt = $db->prepare('SELECT productieorder FROM lo_productieorder');
        $smt->execute();
        $data = $smt->fetchAll();

        foreach ($data as $row): ?>
            <option><?= $row["productieorder"] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-submit">Verder</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sidenote: You're missing a semicolon after `endforeach`.

Comment: also change `post` to `get`

Comment: @pgmann Thanks! FastSnail I'm sorry for the question, but why would I use get? I'm posting this so I can access it from another page, is this correct?

Comment: @YukiKutsuya if you want to show like `index.php?ordernumber=1` then you have to use get.

Comment: @FastSnail I changed it to get, but now it won't continue to the next page.

Comment: @pgmann The semicolon is optional in this case.

Comment: @YukiKutsuya if you read these data[ordernumber..] from php then you have to use `$_GET["ordernumber"]` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the form's method to `GET` and remove the query string from the action:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/logic/orders/werkplaats/index.php" method="get">
```

Now set the `<select>`'s name to `id`. This will be the key in the query string.

```
<select name="id" id="inputProductieorder" class="form-control">
```

Finally, set the value you want the query string to have in each `<option>`.

```
foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <option value="<?= $row["productieorder"] ?>"><?= $row["productieorder"] ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me :). I've done everything you've said, but it won't continue to the next page now. Am I missing something?

Comment: @YukiKutsuya as i said you want to use get from php too.but what do you mean by "won't continue to the next page"?any errors in the console?

Comment: @FastSnail It seems to work perfectly fine now! Thanks you so much ^-^! I think the upload took longer than expected (cheap host, sorry for the misunderstanding).

Comment: @YukiKutsuya nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<option value="<?= $row["productieorder"] ?>"><?= $row["productieorder"] ?></option>
```

This will set the value of the option. And the result will be something like :
index.php?productieorder=value

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm still trying to figure out how I can put the value behind the little ? sign in the url x3

Comment: The form will do that for you (changing POST to GET will also show it in the address bar).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think changing **POST** to **GET** is necessary. That could open up security risks that aren't needed. As long as you're getting the POST data on the index page, you should be fine.

using what you're already have, remove the "?id=", then when capturing the data, use
`$ordernumber = $_POST["productieorder"];`

If you want to use **GET**, what you may need is this:
`<option value="index.php?ordernumber=<?= $row["productieorder"] ?>"><?= $row["productieorder"] ?></option>`
That should give you:
`<option value="index.php?ordernumber=VALUE">VALUE</option>`